# socket io not connecting with socket when use / in URL

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I am developing one flutter app and I have used [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) library and when I pass URL with `/` it is not considering value after that.

For example here is my URL:-
`https://test.com/streaming?sessionId=q76478263784236`

But when I debug my code I found error which says
``` Connection to '``https://test.com:0/socket.io/?sessionId=q76478263784236&EIO=4&transport=websocket#``' was not upgraded to websocket ```

Here is my code to connect socket:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

late IO.Socket _audioSocket;

connectChatSocket({required String sessionId}) async {
  String socketURL = AppUrls.AI_AGENT_URL + "?sessionId=$sessionId";
  print("Chat Socket URL --> ${socketURL}");
  _chatSocket = IO.io(
      socketURL,
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .enableForceNew()
          .build());
  await connectToChatSocket();
}
```